# Node with Mongo start service error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a project written in Node.js with a Mongo database, and I've uploaded it onto a linux server in AWS.

Now, when I try to start the service so it keeps running I get the following error:

```
root@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:/home/mudassir# service happy-king restart ; tail -f /var/log/happy-king.sys.log

happy-king stop/waiting
happy-king start/running, process 7161
[2016-04-19T23:29:39.707Z] (sys) Stopping
[2016-04-19T23:29:39.719Z] (sys) Starting
info: [nodejs/server.js] Express server listening on port undefined
error: [libs/mongoose.js] connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
[2016-04-19T23:52:47.864Z] (sys) Stopping
[2016-04-19T23:52:47.875Z] (sys) Starting
info: [nodejs/server.js] Express server listening on port undefined
error: [libs/mongoose.js] connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
[2016-04-19T23:54:35.564Z] (sys) Stopping
[2016-04-19T23:54:35.576Z] (sys) Starting
info: [nodejs/server.js] Express server listening on port undefined
error: [libs/mongoose.js] connection error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
```

the part where the connection in mongoose.js is as follows:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var log         = require('./log')(module);
var config      = require('./config');

mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoose:uri'));//27017
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
    log.error('connection error:', err.message);
});
db.once('open', function callback () {
    log.info("Connected to DB!");
});
```

And config.json is as follows:

```
{
    "port" : 1337,
    "security": {
        "tokenLife" : 3600
    },
    "mongoose": {
        "uri": "mongodb://localhost/happyk" 
    }
}
```

Would be awesome if you guys can help me figure out what's the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a config issue. Everything seems to be getting set to undefined which tells me there is an issue reading in that config.json file. What does config.js look like? Are you using this: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config?

Comment: That is the entire content for config.json, when I run it locally, or with 
      `node server.js `
It runs fine

Comment: Try this: var config = require(__dirname + '/config.json');